# Chrome not picking up margins for centering, works in safari and firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with Google Chrome not picking up a margin-left and margin-right to center a span in my menuheader. I searched, but I can't seem to find a working solution. It's working fine in Safari and Firefox. Can someone explain or point me in the correct direction ? I'm hoping for a solution without css hacks.

The menu is a horizontal list with 5 elements, the 3th elements is the one where I will place the logo and the title. I'm placing all three into a span and I give the span with the logo a bg image and a text-indent. The span's with the title's are showing perfectly fine in all browsers, the span with the logo only showing fine in safari en firefox, not in chrome.
I load a normalize.css before I load my stylesheet.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<nav class="main-nav">
        <ul id="menu" class="main-nav-list">
          <li class="main-nav-item main-nav-hover"><a href="#pagesection" class="main-nav-link test" title="Over ons">Over ons</a></li>
          <li class="main-nav-item main-nav-hover"><a href="#pagesection" class="main-nav-link" title="Wat we doen">Wat we doen</a></li>
           <li class="main-nav-item">
            <div class="main-nav-home">
                <span class="main-nav-title">title</span>
                <span class="main-nav-subtitle">slogan</span>
                <span class="main-nav-logo">Logo</span>
              </div>
            </li>
          <li class="main-nav-item main-nav-hover"><a href="#pagesection" class="main-nav-link" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li class="main-nav-item main-nav-hover"><a href="#pagesection" class="main-nav-link" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<!-- language: css -->
nav {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #333;
}
.main-nav {
    width: 100%;
}
.main-nav-list {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}
.main-nav-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
    width: calc(100% / 5);
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-nav-home {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.main-nav-title {
  text-decoration: none;
  display : block;
  color: #00ffff;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: 'trenchthin';
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1%;
  }
.main-nav-subtitle {
    text-decoration: none;
    display : block;
    color: #00ffff;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'nexa_lightregular';
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -3%;
    margin-left: -2px;
}
.main-nav-logo {
    display : block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 11;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0;
    padding : 0;
    background : url('../images/logo.png');
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the CSS styles you have on the `<span class="main-nav-logo">Logo</span>`

You are using `position: fixed` which ignores the left and right auto margins.

You can fix by changing the styles to this:

```
.main-nav-logo {
  display : block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  z-index: 11;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: -10%; /* half of the width of the element */
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  padding : 0;
  background : url('../images/logo.png');
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

By adding `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -10%` which is half of the `width: 20%` you will get it centered.

Here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/agyz270o/3/) to show the solution minus the `text-indent: -9999px;` to show its centered.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

After rereading my question when posted to stackoverflow, I figured it out !
I removed the logo span, and I added the background to the main-nav-home div and everything is showing perfect now.

Thanks anyhow ! :-)

SOLVED !

Comment: Ok I was thinking of not changing the markup in case it was intentionally like that. Glad you got it figured out.